# Inform potential employer of other companies

Tags: interviewing, job-search

I am interviewing at different companies and the resources the companies put into this hiring-process vary a lot. For example

1. At Company A I was "only" interviewed for 45 minutes by one manager until now
2. Company B has interviewed me twice (and now asked for a third interview) where multiple people from the department will attend

I mentioned to Company B when we first met that I am looking at several options/companies. Should I stress this again? I feel bad on their behalf that they are spending this many resources on me, given that I may choose a different company.

Comment: Don't feel bad. They are not charities interviewing you out of the goodness of their hearts, they are experienced businesses making rational investments in full knowledge that most of the people they interview won't be hired.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### I feel bad on their behalf that they are spending this many resources on me.

You should not worry about how many people you meet, this is a decision from the company to invest time to select the right candidate. It's extremely costly to hire the wrong guy, then fire him, then start a recruitment process again. Some companies invest more time into selecting a good fit, to ensure that they won't regret it later.

Do not judge the company on the hours they spend on recruitment, this is not a criterion that you will have to live with in your everyday work if you get hired.

#### Should I stress this again?

As the resources spent are not your problem, weigh the pros and cons before making a decision. Think about what happens if you tell them *"Hey, by the way, you're not my only option"*. They might think you don't care, and they might cut the recruitment process already. **I don't see any upside.**

If you can't accept the idea of turning an offer down because "they spent resources", then you should only do one process at a time, but this will significantly slow down your search.

Answer (score 4):

> Should I stress this again?

No. They have their reasons for the processes they have in place. If you don't go with them, this won't be the first time they have gone through their process and not had it work out. It also won't be the last time.